# Calabash for Android on Windows - cannot proceed first test

Tags: ruby, calabash, calabash-android

I know that Calabash is not officially supported by MS but stil developed by community. After configuration I always get the same error:

```
C:\Users\XXX YYY\CalabashCucumberTest>bundle exec calabash-android run io.apk
No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
WARNING: skipped META-INF/CERT.RSA as unsafe
Traceback (most recent call last):
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/bin/calabash-android:86:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16:in `calabash_run'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:107:in `build_test_server_if_needed'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:2:in `calabash_build'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:169:in `fingerprint_from_apk'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:170:in `block in fingerprint_from_apk'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:170:in `chdir'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.8/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:188:in `block (2 levels) in fingerprint_from_apk': No signature files found in META-INF. Cannot proceed. (RuntimeError)
```

I followed official Github tutorial. I tried different apps, real and emulated devices - result is the same. Can anyone help me with configuration? Maybe I have to use other versions than latest Ruby and selected gems?